# Vector Space Isomorphism related to Tensor Product

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products, vector-space-isomorphism

$V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces over $k$. I need a basis free isomorphism between $V^*\otimes_{k} W^*$ and $Bil_{k}(V\times W,k)$.

My attempt: We have a bilinear map $V^*\times W^*\rightarrow Bil_{k}(V\times W,k)$ sending $(f,g)\mapsto \Big((v,w)\mapsto f(v)g(w)\Big)$. This induces a linear map from $V^*\otimes W^*\rightarrow Bil_{k}(V\times W,k)$, sending $f\otimes g\mapsto \Big((v,w)\mapsto f(v)g(w)\Big)$.
I need a $k$-linear map from the other direction so that the compositions will be identity.

Comment: Here is another way to do it: show that $Bil_k(V \times W, k)$ satisfies the universal property of $V^* \otimes W^*$, then by the usual nonsense there is a unique isomorphism.

Comment: That's nice but I actually need to know the isomorphism to do the next set of problems. It would be better if we can construct an isomorphism.